# Angular: How to access parameters outside of $timeout callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have a timeout loop like this:

```
var somedata = {
        autoRefreshInterval: 300,
        autoRefreshInSec: 300,
        myTimeout: null,
        doRefresh: _doRefresh,
        onTimeout: function () {
            this.autoRefreshInSec--;
            if (this.autoRefreshInSec <= 0) {
                this.autoRefreshInSec = this.autoRefreshInterval; 
                this.doRefresh();
            }
            this.myTimeout = $timeout(this.onTimeout, 1000);
        },
        startTimer: function () {
            this.autoRefreshInSec = this.autoRefreshInterval;
            this.myTimeout = $timeout(this.onTimeout, 1000);
        },
        stopTimer: function () {
            $timeout.cancel(this.myTimeout);
        },
    }
```

It appears that the "this" doesn't work inside of onTimeout callback function, while it works fine for startTimer and stopTimer. How to fix it?

UPDATE:

Since this is lost inside the onTimeout based on one of the answers below, I tried to pass it into like this:

```
onTimeout: function (self) {
    self.autoRefreshInSec--;
    if (self.autoRefreshInSec <= 0) {
        self.autoRefreshInSec = self.autoRefreshInterval;  // Set it here so that it does't start refresh right away. It will be reset when refresh is done.
        self.doRefresh();
    }
    self.myTimeout = $timeout(self.onTimeout(self), 1000);
},
startTimer: function () {
    this.autoRefreshInSec = this.autoRefreshInterval;
    this.myTimeout = $timeout(this.onTimeout(this), 1000);
},
```

Strangely, when I debug through the code, it seems working. However, once I removed the break points, self.doRefresh() is fired continuously. Why?

UPDATE 2:

Okay, I created a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qY86q/1 to illustrate the problem.

Comment: What does it have to do with `AngularJS`?

Comment: $timeout is an AngularJS function, right?

Comment: Angular has [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).  Where do you inject it in your code?

Comment: $timeout is injected correctly. That's not my question. My question is from inside of onTimeout (which is called by $timeout) how to access something like autoRefreshInSec? "this" (as I showed) is not working.

Comment: `this` refers to the function you are in.  So inside your `$timeout.cancel()` it refers to the function `$timeout`.  Just use the name itself.

Comment: @Kousha it doesn't work. If I change this.autoRefreshInSec to autoRefreshInSec, it says "autoRefreshInSec" is not defined. As I said, "this" is working everywhere except inside onTimeout callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Function.prototype.bind()

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

### Solution for your case

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .service('timerService', function($timeout) {
    var _timer = {
      autoRefreshInterval: 300,
      autoRefreshInSec: 300,
      myTimeout: null,
      onTimeout: function() {
        this.autoRefreshInSec -= 1;
        if (this.autoRefreshInSec <= 0) {
          this.autoRefreshInSec = this.autoRefreshInterval;
          console.log('refreshing');
        }
        console.log('time: ', this.autoRefreshInSec);
        this.myTimeout = $timeout(this.onTimeout.bind(this), 1000);
      },
      startTimer: function() {
        if (this.myTimeout) {
          this.stopTimer(this.myTimeout)
        }
        this.autoRefreshInSec = this.autoRefreshInterval;
        this.myTimeout = $timeout(this.onTimeout.bind(this), 1000);
      },
      stopTimer: $timeout.cancel // see note(1)
    };
    var context = {
      timer: _timer
    };
    return context;
  }).controller('PrefsCtrl', function PrefsCtrl($scope, timerService) {
    $scope.timer = timerService.timer;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PrefsCtrl">
    <button ng-click="timer.startTimer()">Click to Start or Reset Timer</button>
    <div>{{timer.autoRefreshInSec}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**note(1)**, this is shorcut for

```
stopTimer: function(timer) {
   $timeout.cancel(timer)
}
```

Comment: So, how do I apply your solution to my problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. "This" is actually a window object inside onTimeout as I debug through it. This.autoRefreshInSec is undefined.

Comment: Inside startTimeout `this` points to global (window) object – You have implemented some mix of my proposal solution.

Comment: Please see my update with a link to JFiddle project. Hope you can fix it there.

Comment: Sorry about that. The link to jsfiddle is up-to-date now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript binding issue.

Try:

```
var somedata;  // now this can be referenced in the angular.bind call
somedata = {
    onTimeout: angular.bind(somedata, function () {
        this.autoRefreshInSec--;
        if (this.autoRefreshInSec <= 0) {
            this.autoRefreshInSec = this.autoRefreshInterval; 
            this.doRefresh();
        }
        this.myTimeout = $timeout(this.onTimeout, 1000);
    })
}
```

which will ensure the `this` at the time that function is called is "bound" to `somedata` inside the callback.

Comment: ah yes you are correct. Too quick with the response. But it still is a binding issue (nothing magic to angular)

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't seem to work either. "this" in this.autoRefreshInSec still points to window.